# Laravel Maatwebsite excel array

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a newbie in Laravel, but I'm using laravel's Maatwebsite\Excel Library v3 to export excel. But I'm having some problems exporting my array data.

here is my code

```
    <?php

namespace App\Exports;
use App\Team;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

class RegisteredMemberExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings
{
    use Exportable;

    public function collection()
    {

     $data = Team::where('reg', 1)->get();       

        return collect([
            [
                'name' => $data->name,
                'email' => $data->email
            ]
        ]);
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'name',
            'email'
        ];
    }

}
```

the collect should be

```
return collect
([
            [
                'name' => 'Povilas',
                'email' => 'povilas@laraveldaily.com'
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Taylor',
                'email' => 'taylor@laravel.com'
            ]
        ]);
```

I can't use a loop inside the collect method return. 
Can I please have some help?

Comment: what data do you want from coolection

Comment: What would you want to do with the loop?

Answer (score 2):

You can directly filter the values you need from your Eloquent model using a list of attributes as a parameter for the `get` method.

```
$data = Team::where('reg', 1)->get(['name', 'email']);

return collect($data->toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `each` or `map` or any chain method you want [Laravel Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-collections#available-methods) like this:

```
return collect([
                 ['name' => 'Povilas','email'=>'povilas@laraveldaily.com'],
                 ['name' => 'Taylor','email' => 'taylor@laravel.com']
              ])->each(function($value){
                 return $value; // Do what you want here
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromArray` concern which works the same as `FromCollection`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromArray;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

class RegisteredMemberExport implements FromArray, WithHeadings
{
    public function array(): array
    {
        return [
            [
                'name' => 'Povilas',
                'email' => 'povilas@laraveldaily.com',
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Taylor',
                'email' => 'taylor@laravel.com',
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'name',
            'email',
        ];
    }
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/2039#issuecomment-461396838)